A Combinatorial Geometry problem from BDMO 2024
Samin is colouring the vertices of a regular -gon. He is using the colours red, blue and
yellow. He coloured the vertices in a way such that the number of red coloured vertices (resp blue, yellow)
is odd. Now, Samin tells Tahmid to pick three vertices from these  vertices so
that they make an isosceles triangle and all three vertices have different colours. Can Tahmid
pick such three vertices? Show mathematically.
I have tried breaking up 17-gon into two pieces with diagonally opposite number but it don't give me any clue.I have sat for the exam this year,but couldn't solve after trying hard.
Please help me.
source:Bdmo 2024 national junior question

Suppose that (for illustrative purposes) you selected vertices 1, 3, and 5, and formed the corresponding triangle.  What would each of the angles be?

Hint: Count Red-Blue edges.
Given that the number of red (and separately blue) colored vertices are odd, show that  the number of Red-Blue edges is odd.

 Since 17 is odd and not a multiple of 3, show that each edge occurs in exactly 3 isosceles triangles.


 Assume that there is no isosceles tricolored triangle, then show that the number of Red-Blue edges is even.

This is a contradiction, so the assumption is false and there is a tricolored isosceles triangle.

Great, I have proved the problem, Thank you for your solution

this shows there must be a tricolored triangle but why does it have to be isosceles?

@C.C.  Since there is an odd number vertices of each color, hence there is at least 1 vertex of each color, so obviously there is a tricolored triangle without having to do much work.  $\quad$ Modify your proof to focus only on isosceles triangles. I added a further hint if you need it. (I also updated the assumption to indicate it's only of isosceles tri-colored triangles)

@CalvinLin Thanks, so I can count all red-blue edges by summing over each isosceles $\triangle$ obtaining an overcount $s$, then divide it by $3$. $s$ is even (each isosceles $\triangle$ contributes either $0$ or $2$ to $s$) so $s/3$ is even.
